# Is this a viable session expire?

Tags: php, session, expired-sessions

Basically what I wanted was to create a session with an expire time of 24 hours.
And I wrote this:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['TIME_START']) || $_SESSION['TIME_START'] < time()) {
        $_SESSION['TIME_START'] = time();
} else if ($_SESSION['TIME_START'] > 60 * 60 * 24) {
    session_destroy();
}
```

I would like to know if this is a valid, viable or good practice to do it.
Thanks!

Comment: would be better to handle with cookies

Comment: A session _uses_ a cookie. Look at [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - A session lifetime, is set by default by the server side. Check session.gc_maxlifetime parameter in php.ini

2 - As Rakesh Sharma said, maybe better to use Cookies

3 - `if (!isset($_SESSION['TIME_START']) || $_SESSION['TIME_START'] < time()) {` in this case, you will reset your $_SESSION['TIME_START'] each time the user go through this function under the 24 hours requested in your needs. Is that wanted ?

Comment: Yes, I want the session to reset every time they go through this function, sorry if this was a stupid question I've only been into PHP for 5 days.

Comment: @McQueso can you explain what are your requirements exactly ?

Comment: Is for a login session, to see for how much time they've been logged in, each day they would have to log in again

Comment: In this case, use cookies it's better than using Sessions for your requirements.